# Jumpy scrolling on Windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, cross-browser

I have a situation when a fixed-size and overflow:hidden element in a browser window contains a very long image, which is basically a vertical sequence of animation frames.

The animation has to occur when a user is scrolling the window. Specifically, advance in $(window).scrollTop() implies corresponding shift in animation frames.

Simple linear dependency between scroll offset and frame number gives me excellent smooth animation on Mac OS, but Windows has a "jumpy" scroll and we instead see an immediate 'jump' from one frame to another.

Now, as though I do feel I'm going to need to detect offset delta between scroll events, and animate the frame advance accordingly using time-based iterations, the question stands: is there a way to make Windows generate a smoother change in scroll offset somewhat like Mac OS does?

Thank you.

Comment: Hm...I may have seen this effect before. Is this only when you use the mouse scroll wheel to scroll? (ie, each 'click' of the wheel makes the image jump once as the scroll movement completes)

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about window "jumping" with each scroll event fired by the browser. While my animation has to be bound to scroll and yet remain smooth.